# How to take data from a large string and put it into object fields?

Tags: java, string

Java project. I have a big string coming from command line like :

```
 Total 5.89452: not packed
  0|PE Header|0|1024|3.04974: not packed
  1|Section(0)['.text']|1024|420352|5.83462: not packed
  2|Section(1)['.rdata']|421376|78336|4.84439: not packed
  3|Section(2)['.data']|499712|3584|2.61044: not packed
  4|Section(3)['.pdata']|503296|12800|5.54411: not packed
  5|Section(4)['.rsrc']|516096|1536|3.90572: not packed
  6|Section(5)['.reloc']|517632|2560|4.89783: not packed
  7|Overlay|520192|9088|7.37885: packed
```

And i have to separate strings ,then put into object fileds:

```
public class DieEntropy {
    private String name;
    private String bias;
    private String size; 
    private String entropy; 
    private String status; 
}
```

where:

```
name = Section(0)['.text']
bias = 1024
size = 420352
entropy = 5.83462:
status = not packed
```

and other the same way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: You might do `line.split("\\||:")` for this one as the colon is also a delimiter

Comment: I splited big string ,but i can't find algorithm to put right string into right position in object , this was my trouble at the first place

Answer (score 0):

Having this class:

```
public class DieEntropy {
    private String name;
    private String bias;
    private String size; 
    private String entropy; 
    private String status; 
}
```

You are not allowed to modify the values of the fields from outside because they are `private` (except the rare case that the class is a nested class).